# QGIS 3.2 Layout Map render/cache/rectangle no longer available

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, layouts

In previous version of QGIS when using the print composer there was an option to have the map displayed as a rectangle, cached or render. This was particularly useful when the map showed lots of information and took a long time to load/redraw. I am setting up a template to auto generate a lot of maps using an atlas but can no longer find this option and it takes quite a while to render the map, even though i don't need to see it, just want to export it. Does anyone know if this feature has been removed completely, hidden somewhere else or will be implemented back in further versions?

Comment: Same problem here. If working with several maps and a lot of data. Arranging the items in the map composer is quite slow - so I really miss the possibility to display the maps as a rectangle and rearrange them rapidly. Matthias

Comment: But ... now all I see is an empty rectangle. How do I make the map actually display? EDIt when I updted QGIS it altered all the extents saved in my print views, so I had to recreate ALL of them

Answer (score 6):

It's been removed, as a result of the map items now rendering in a background thread. (Because the map renders in the background, it no longer causes the "hangs" while rendering, so even for complex maps you can continue to work within the layout designer while the map renders away in the background).

Comment: OK thanks for the update. Its a shame as it was quite useful making panning/ zooming etc a lot faster when I had lots of different pages and maps within a single composer/layout. Though looking into it a bit more yesterday I realised that reports map be what I want to be using for that sort of thing anyway!